# Thunderbird: move Quick Filter Bar to main panel

Tags: thunderbird

I did have identical question couple of years ago, and it was [successfully solved here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588468/thunderbird-move-quick-filter-toolbar-to-main-panel)

But now I have upgraded from Thunderbird 68 to 102, and the solution no longer works. Thunderbird 102 changed considerably since version 68, and the files `messenger.xul` and `messageWindow.xul` no longer exist.

How can I move the `Quick Filter Bar` to main panel, as shown here?

[image]

the goal is to:

1. move the `Quick Filter Bar` text input field up, to the main panel
2. move the attachment icon next to the `Quick Filter Bar`
3. remove the rest of the useless buttons/icons (pin, Unread, Starred, Contact, Tags)
4. remove the default text: "Filter these messages <Ctr+Shift+K>"

So, in the end it should look like this:

[image]

**Bonus:** if the two useless icons (show spaces toolbar, work offline) in the left bottom corner could be removed, that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the modified patch that works for 102:

```
diff --git a/omni/chrome/classic/skin/classic/messenger/shared/quickFilterBar.css b/omni/chrome/classic/skin/classic/messenger/shared/quickFilterBar.css
index 48d17a0..6c19572 100644
--- a/omni/chrome/classic/skin/classic/messenger/shared/quickFilterBar.css
+++ b/omni/chrome/classic/skin/classic/messenger/shared/quickFilterBar.css
@@ -55,7 +55,7 @@
 }
 
 #qfb-results-label {
-  color: GrayText;
+  color: #fff200;
   text-align: end;
   visibility: hidden;
 }
diff --git a/omni/chrome/en-US/locale/en-US/messenger/quickFilterBar.dtd b/omni/chrome/en-US/locale/en-US/messenger/quickFilterBar.dtd
index 39ef1ad..104b8e4 100644
--- a/omni/chrome/en-US/locale/en-US/messenger/quickFilterBar.dtd
+++ b/omni/chrome/en-US/locale/en-US/messenger/quickFilterBar.dtd
@@ -152,7 +152,7 @@
      box faster.
      -->
 <!ENTITY quickFilterBar.textbox.emptyText.base1
-         "Filter these messages #1">
+         "">
 
 <!-- LOCALIZATION NOTE (quickFilterBar.show.key2):
      This is the key used to show the quick filter bar. -->
diff --git a/omni/chrome/messenger/content/messenger/folderDisplay.js b/omni/chrome/messenger/content/messenger/folderDisplay.js
index fa1a6a5..3d97e8a 100644
--- a/omni/chrome/messenger/content/messenger/folderDisplay.js
+++ b/omni/chrome/messenger/content/messenger/folderDisplay.js
@@ -454,14 +454,12 @@ FolderDisplayWidget.prototype = {
   DEFAULT_COLUMNS: [
     "threadCol",
     "attachmentCol",
-    "flaggedCol",
     "subjectCol",
-    "unreadButtonColHeader",
     "senderCol", // news folders or incoming folders when correspondents not in use
     "recipientCol", // outgoing folders when correspondents not in use
     "correspondentCol", // mail folders
-    "junkStatusCol",
     "dateCol",
+    "sizeCol",
     "locationCol", // multiple-folder backed folders
   ],
 
diff --git a/omni/chrome/messenger/content/messenger/messageWindow.xhtml b/omni/chrome/messenger/content/messenger/messageWindow.xhtml
index 2f7f3d4..3ea2886 100644
--- a/omni/chrome/messenger/content/messenger/messageWindow.xhtml
+++ b/omni/chrome/messenger/content/messenger/messageWindow.xhtml
@@ -4651,7 +4651,7 @@
            fullscreentoolbar="true" mode="full"
            customizable="true"
            context="toolbar-context-menu"
-           defaultset="button-getmsg,button-newmsg,separator,button-tag,qfb-show-filter-bar,spring,gloda-search,button-appmenu">
+           defaultset="button-getmsg,button-newmsg,separator,button-tag,separator,qfb-sticky,qfb-results-label,qfb-qs-textbox,qfb-attachment,qfb-show-filter-bar,spring,gloda-search,button-appmenu">
   </toolbar>
   </toolbox>
 
diff --git a/omni/chrome/messenger/content/messenger/messenger.xhtml b/omni/chrome/messenger/content/messenger/messenger.xhtml
index 68bd1e6..bc7b503 100644
--- a/omni/chrome/messenger/content/messenger/messenger.xhtml
+++ b/omni/chrome/messenger/content/messenger/messenger.xhtml
@@ -7099,6 +7099,33 @@
         <menuseparator id="button-afterTagRemoveAllSeparator"/>
       </menupopup>
     </toolbarbutton>
+        <toolbarbutton id="qfb-sticky" type="checkbox"
+                       class="toolbarbutton-1 icon-only" orient="horizontal"
+                       crop="none" style="min-width:16px;"
+                       tooltiptext="&quickFilterBar.sticky.tooltip;"
+                       />
+        <label id="qfb-results-label"
+               style="min-width:&quickFilterBar.resultsLabel.minWidth;"
+               value=""
+               somefmtstring="&quickFilterBar.resultsLabel.some.formatString;"
+               noresultsstring="&quickFilterBar.resultsLabel.none;"
+               />
+        <search-textbox id="qfb-qs-textbox"
+                        flex="3"
+                        class="themeableSearchBox"
+                        placeholder=""
+                        emptytextbase="&quickFilterBar.textbox.emptyText.base1;"
+                        keyLabelNonMac="&quickFilterBar.textbox.emptyText.keyLabel2.nonmac;"
+                        keyLabelMac="&quickFilterBar.textbox.emptyText.keyLabel2.mac;"
+                        timeout="500"
+                        maxlength="192"
+                        width="320"
+                        style="min-width:280px;"/>
+          <toolbarbutton id="qfb-attachment" type="checkbox"
+                         class="toolbarbutton-1" orient="horizontal"
+                         crop="none" style="min-width:16px;"
+                         label="&quickFilterBar.attachment.label;"
+                         tooltiptext="&quickFilterBar.attachment.tooltip;"/>
     <toolbarbutton id="qfb-show-filter-bar"
                    class="toolbarbutton-1"
                    type="checkbox"
@@ -7281,7 +7308,7 @@
            fullscreentoolbar="true" mode="full"
            customizable="true"
            context="toolbar-context-menu"
-           defaultset="button-getmsg,button-newmsg,separator,button-tag,qfb-show-filter-bar,spring,gloda-search,button-appmenu">
+           defaultset="button-getmsg,button-newmsg,separator,button-tag,separator,qfb-sticky,qfb-results-label,qfb-qs-textbox,qfb-attachment,qfb-show-filter-bar,spring,gloda-search,button-appmenu">
   </toolbar>
           </toolbox>
 
@@ -7363,12 +7390,13 @@
             <vbox flex="1">
               <box orient="vertical" id="messagesBox" flex="1">
 
-    <vbox id="quick-filter-bar" class="themeable-brighttext">
+    <vbox id="quick-filter-bar" class="themeable-brighttext" hidden="true">
       <hbox id="quick-filter-bar-main-bar" align="center"
             onoverflow="QuickFilterBarMuxer.onOverflow();"
             >
         <toolbarbutton id="qfb-sticky" type="checkbox"
                        class="toolbarbutton-1 icon-only" orient="horizontal"
+                       hidden="true"
                        crop="none" style="min-width:16px;"
                        tooltiptext="&quickFilterBar.sticky.tooltip;"
                        />
@@ -7377,30 +7405,36 @@
           <toolbarseparator id="qfb-separator"/>
           <toolbarbutton id="qfb-unread" type="checkbox"
                          class="toolbarbutton-1" orient="horizontal"
+                         hidden="true"
                          crop="none" style="min-width:16px;"
                          label="&quickFilterBar.unread.label;"
                          tooltiptext="&quickFilterBar.unread.tooltip;"
                          />
           <toolbarbutton id="qfb-starred" type="checkbox"
                          class="toolbarbutton-1" orient="horizontal"
+                         hidden="true"
                          crop="none" style="min-width:16px;"
                          label="&quickFilterBar.starred.label;"
                          tooltiptext="&quickFilterBar.starred.tooltip;"
                          />
           <toolbarbutton id="qfb-inaddrbook" type="checkbox"
                          class="toolbarbutton-1" orient="horizontal"
+                         hidden="true"
                          crop="none" style="min-width:16px;"
                          label="&quickFilterBar.inaddrbook.label;"
                          tooltiptext="&quickFilterBar.inaddrbook.tooltip;"
                          />
           <toolbarbutton id="qfb-tags" type="checkbox"
                          class="toolbarbutton-1" orient="horizontal"
+                         hidden="true"
                          crop="none" style="min-width:16px;"
                          label="&quickFilterBar.tags.label;"
                          tooltiptext="&quickFilterBar.tags.tooltip;"
                          />
+
           <toolbarbutton id="qfb-attachment" type="checkbox"
                          class="toolbarbutton-1" orient="horizontal"
+                         hidden="true"
                          crop="none" style="min-width:16px;"
                          label="&quickFilterBar.attachment.label;"
                          tooltiptext="&quickFilterBar.attachment.tooltip;"/>
@@ -7410,6 +7444,7 @@
              in dimensions causes ugly flex rearrangement of the textbox. -->
         <label id="qfb-results-label"
                style="min-width:&quickFilterBar.resultsLabel.minWidth;"
+               hidden="true"
                value=""
                somefmtstring="&quickFilterBar.resultsLabel.some.formatString;"
                noresultsstring="&quickFilterBar.resultsLabel.none;"
@@ -7417,6 +7452,7 @@
         <search-textbox id="qfb-qs-textbox"
                         flex="3"
                         class="themeableSearchBox"
+                        hidden="true"
                         placeholder=""
                         emptytextbase="&quickFilterBar.textbox.emptyText.base1;"
                         keyLabelNonMac="&quickFilterBar.textbox.emptyText.keyLabel2.nonmac;"
```